# Simple VJ software for background video in live concert

Tags: video

Here's what I am trying to accomplish: I have a bunch of AVI videos between which I need to switch back/forth as songs play in the concert.

The only requirements for the software are that:

- videos need to be seamless (no player GUI showing up on the projection)
- I can go to previous/next video in the playlist through the keyboard
- when switching between videos in the playlist, there should be a cross-fade or fade-out / fade-in transition.

Can you point me towards a piece of software that can do that for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few:

- [freemix](http://freemix.forja.rediris.es/)
- [FreeJ](http://freej.dyne.org/)
- [LiVES](http://lives.sourceforge.net/)
- [veejay](http://www.veejayhq.net/)

Answer (score 0):

VLC should do the job but I think you would need to put your own fadeouts at the end of the videos. I've also used the GUI of Mplayer for this, like with VLC though you need to keep the playlist window on a second monitor.

MPV player also enables playing videos in a sequence. Simply pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> advances to the next video.

GLMixer allows you to mix videos live, more like a VJ software. You can fade and crossfade with it. Ubuntu/Debian installation packages are available for Ubuntu 15.04 and 14.10. See:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/glmixer/files/?source=navbar

and/or

http://sourceforge.net/projects/glmixer

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Le Biniou](https://biniou.net). Installation instructions [here](https://codepre.com/lebiniou-music-visualization-and-vjing-software.html).